# update checkboxes using ajax php mysqli

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

this is my modal

```
 <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="exampleModal<?php echo $row['t_id'] ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel<?php echo $row['t_id'] ?>">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Termin Ansicht <font color="red">ID</font>: <b><?php echo $row['t_id'] ?></b> <font color="red">Call Agent</font>: <b><?php echo $row['username'] ?></b>  <font color="red">Call Datum</font>: <b><?php echo date("d.m.y" , strtotime($row['datum'])) ?></b></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
          <form>
                              <div class="row">

                                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                                      <input type="text" id="username" value="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>"  class="form-control">
                                  </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                      <input type="text" id="t_id" value="<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>"  class="form-control">
                                </div>


                              </div>
                              <br>

                            <div class="row">
                              <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Anrede</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <input type="text" id="anrede<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['anrede']; ?>" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                                  <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Vorname</label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                                      <input type="text"  id="vorname<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['vorname']; ?>"  class="form-control" onselectstart="return false" onpaste="return false;" onCopy="return false" onCut="return false" onDrag="return false" onDrop="return false">
                                  </div>
                                <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Nachname</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                      <input type="text" id="nachname<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['nachname']; ?>"  class="form-control" onselectstart="return false" onpaste="return false;" onCopy="return false" onCut="return false" onDrag="return false" onDrop="return false">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <br>
                            <div class="row">
                                  <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Strasse</label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                                      <input type="text" id="strasse<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['strasse']; ?>"  class="form-control">

                                  </div>
                                <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">PLZ</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                      <input type="text" id="plz<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['plz']; ?>"  class="form-control">
                                </div>

                                <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Ort</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                      <input type="text" id="ort<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['ort']; ?>"  class="form-control">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <br>
                             <div class="row">
                                  <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Krankenkasse</label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                                      <input type="text" id="krankenkasse<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['krankenkasse']; ?>"  class="form-control">

                                  </div>
                                <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Seit</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                      <input type="text" id="seit<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['seit']; ?>"  class="form-control">
                                </div>

                                <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Personen</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-1">
                                      <input type="text" id="personen<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['personen']; ?>"  class="form-control">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <br>


                              <div class="row">
                                  <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Telefon</label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-2">
                                      <input type="text" id="telefon<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['telefon']; ?>"   class="form-control">

                                  </div>
                                <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Termin</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                      <input type="date" id="termin<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['termin']; ?>"  class="form-control">
                                </div>

                                <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Uhrzeit</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                      <input type="text" id="time<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo  date("H:i", strtotime($row['time'])) ?>" class="form-control">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="vermittler<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>" value='<?php echo $row['vermittler'];?>'>
                                        <option ><?php echo $row['vermittler'];?></option>
                                    <?php
                                    $result1 = ("SELECT * FROM users where type='berater'") or mysql_error(); 
                                $ilaz=mysql_query($result1);
                                while($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($ilaz)){

                                ?>
                                <option id="berater" value = "<?php echo $rowa['username']; ?>" >
                                    <?php echo $rowa['username']; ?>
                                </option>
                                <?php
                                }
                                ?>


                                        </select>  
                                        </div>
                              </div>

                            <br>


                               <div class="row">
                                      <label for="ccomment" class="control-label col-lg-2">Bemerkung</label>
                                      <div class="col-lg-4">
                                          <textarea class="form-control "  id="coment<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>" required><?php echo $row['coment']; ?></textarea>
                                      </div>

                                      <label for="ccomment" class="control-label col-lg-1">Feedback</label>
                                      <div class="col-lg-4">
                                          <textarea class="form-control "  id="feedback<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>" ></textarea>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                                    <br>

                                    <div class="row">
                                   <?php

                                   $bfeedback = ("select id, user, feedback_b, datum from b_feedback where id='". (int)$_GET['t_id']."' order by datum desc" ) or mysql_error();

                                   $bresult = mysql_query($bfeedback);
                                   if($bfeedback === FALSE) { 
                                            die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
                                        }

                                   while($beraterfeedback = mysql_fetch_array($bresult)){
                                       ?>
                                       <label for="b_feedback" class="control-label col-lg-2"><?php #echo $beraterfeedback['user'] ?><?php #echo $beraterfeedback['datum'] ?></label>

                                        <td><font color="red"><?php echo $beraterfeedback['user'] ?></font></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <td><?php echo $beraterfeedback['datum'] ?></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <td><?php echo $beraterfeedback['feedback_b'] ?></td><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<hr>

                                       <?php

                                   }

                                   ?>


                                  </div>

                                <br>    
                        <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-sm-20">
                                  <?php
                                        $iAstatus = explode(",",$row['Astatus']);
                                        foreach($arrAstatus as $aAstatus)
                                        {
                                            if(in_array($aAstatus,$iAstatus))
                                                echo "<label class='col-sm-1 control-label'><input type='checkbox' class='s'  value='".$aAstatus."'  checked> .$aAstatus. </label>";                    
                                            else
                                                echo "<label class='col-sm-1 control-label'><input type='checkbox' class='s'  value='".$aAstatus."'> .$aAstatus.</label>" ;                 

                                        }
                                  ?>
                                </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                                          <input type="text" id="positiv<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['abschluss']; ?>"  class="form-control">
                                    </div>

                            </div>
                            <br>
                                    <div class="row">
                                  <label class="col-sm-5 control-label"><p style="color:red"><font size="2">Personen Angaben (Namen, Geburtsdatum)?</font></p></label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-5">
                                          <textarea class="form-control " id="personen_angaben<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>" ><?php echo $row['personen_angaben']; ?></textarea>
                                  </div>
                              </div>


                                <br>  
                             <div class="row">
                                  <label class="col-sm-5 control-label"><p style="color:red"><font size="2">Sind Sie (bzw. jemand in Ihrem Haushalt) momentan in &auml;rztliche Behandlung/Therapie(Physio) oder steht Ihnen eine Behandlung bevor?</font></p></label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-5">
                                      <input class="form-control"  type="text" id="fr_1<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['fr_1']; ?>" >
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <br>
                              <div class="row">
                                  <label class="col-sm-5 control-label"><p style="color:red"><font size="2">Zusatzfrage wenn JA- Dies k&ouml;nnte Auswirkungen auf Ihren Wechsel haben. Deshalb, welcher Art ist denn diese Behandlung?</font></p></label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-5">
                                      <input class="form-control"  type="text" id="fr_2<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['fr_2']; ?>">
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <br>
                            <div class="row">
                                  <label class="col-sm-5 control-label"><p style="color:red"><font size="2">Nehmen Sie (bzw. jemand in Ihrem Haushalt) regelm&auml;ssig Medikamente?</font></p></label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-5">
                                      <input class="form-control"  type="text" id="z_fr_2<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['z_fr_2']; ?>">
                                  </div>
                              </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                  <label class="col-sm-5 control-label"><font size="2"><p style="color:red">Zusatzfrage wenn JA- Was sind das f&uuml;r Medikamente oder f&uuml;r was m&uuml;ssen Sie diese nehmen?</p></font></label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-5">
                                      <input class="form-control"  id="fr_3<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['fr_3']; ?>" >
                                  </div>
                              </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                  <label class="col-sm-5 control-label"><font size="2"><p style="color:red">Hatten Sie (bzw. jemand an Ihrem Haushalt) in den letzten 10 Jahren eine Operation oder steht eine bevor?</p></font></label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-5">
                                      <input class="form-control"  type="text" id="z_fr_3<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['z_fr_3']; ?>">
                                  </div>
                              </div>

                             <div class="row">
                                  <label class="col-sm-5 control-label"><font size="2"><p style="color:red">Was f&uuml;r eine Operation wann /ist das?</p></font></label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-5">
                                      <input class="form-control"  type="text" id="fr_4<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['fr_4']; ?>" >
                                  </div>
                              </div>

                             <div class="row">
                                  <label class="col-sm-5 control-label"><font size="2"><p style="color:red">Wenn die Operation in der Vergangenheit war: beziehen Sie nun eine IV-Rente oder ist dies folgenlos geheilt?</p></font></label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-5">
                                      <input class="form-control"  type="text" id="z_fr_4<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['z_fr_4']; ?>" >
                                  </div>
                              </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                  <label class="col-sm-5 control-label"><font size="2"><p style="color:red">Falls 1 Person krank ist - K&ouml;nnen Sie sich vorstellen, einen Teil Ihrer Familie zu versichern?</p></font></label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-5">
                                      <input class="form-control"  type="text" id="fr_5<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['fr_5']; ?>"  >
                                  </div>
                              </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                  <label class="col-sm-5 control-label"><font size="2">Status</font></label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-5">
                                      <input class="form-control"  type="text" id="fr_6<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['status']; ?>">
                                  </div>
                              </div>





                            <div class="row">
                             <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"> </label>
                             <div class="col-sm-3">

                            </div>

                            </div>   
                          </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button"  onclick="updatedata('<?php echo $row['t_id'] ?>')" data-dismiss="modal"  class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

and this jquery ajax

```
function updatedata(str){

var t_id = str;
var anrede = $('#anrede'+str).val();
var vorname = $('#vorname'+str).val();
var nachname = $('#nachname'+str).val();
var strasse = $('#strasse'+str).val();
var plz = $('#plz'+str).val();
var ort = $('#ort'+str).val();
var krankenkasse = $('#krankenkasse'+str).val();
var seit = $('#seit'+str).val();
var personen = $('#personen'+str).val();
var telefon = $('#telefon'+str).val();
var termin = $('#termin'+str).val();
var time = $('#time'+str).val();
var vermittler = $('#vermittler'+str).val();
var coment = $('#coment'+str).val();
var feedback = $('#feedback'+str).val();
var s = new Array();
    $("input:checked").each(function() {
       s.push($(this).val());
    });


var positiv = $('#positiv'+str).val();
var personen_angaben = $('#personen_angaben'+str).val();
var fr_1 = $('#fr_1'+str).val();
var fr_2 = $('#fr_2'+str).val();
var z_fr_2 = $('#z_fr_2'+str).val();
var fr_3 = $('#fr_3'+str).val();
var z_fr_3 = $('#z_fr_3'+str).val();
var fr_4 = $('#fr_4'+str).val();
var z_fr_4 = $('#z_fr_4'+str).val();
var fr_5 = $('#fr_5'+str).val();
var fr_6 = $('#fr_6'+str).val();

var datas="anrede="+anrede+"&vorname="+vorname+"&nachname="+nachname+"&strasse="+strasse+"&plz="+plz+"&ort="+ort+"&krankenkasse="+krankenkasse+"&seit="+seit+"&personen="+personen+"&telefon="+telefon+"&termin="+termin+"&time="+time+"&vermittler="+vermittler+"&coment="+coment+"&feedback="+feedback+"&s[]="+s+"&positiv="+positiv+"&personen_angaben="+personen_angaben+"&fr_1="+fr_1+"&fr_2="+fr_2+"&z_fr_2="+z_fr_2+"&fr_3="+fr_3+"&z_fr_3="+z_fr_3+"&fr_4="+fr_4+"&z_fr_4="+z_fr_4+"&fr_5="+fr_5+"&fr_6="+fr_6;                                                                        
  alert(datas);
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "updatedata.php?t_id="+t_id,
   data: datas,
   cache: false
}).done(function( data ) {
  $('#info').html(data);
    viewdata();
});
}
```

and this the php array

```
$arrAstatus = array("Wollte k T","Kunde Ni err.","St .Gef","N.Zuhaus","Offen","Negativ","MJV","Behan.","Abgesagt","Positiv");
```

Now when i submit the form it update all unchecked checkboxes.

how can i do that it update only checked checkboxes and after refresh to show me it checked

Comment: Are you saying you want to know how to do this with Ajax?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: when are you declaring `$aAstatus` and `$iAstatus`, what are their values?

Comment: the `id` of any HTML element should not be an array `[]`. I think you are thinking of the `name` attribute

Comment: stay away from using old HTML syntax. `<font>` is no longer supported in HTML5.

Comment: Haha. that was a typo. I updated my comment. I actually meant `<font>`. Refresh your page.

Comment: Yeah, lol . I figured. I was like ohhhh no.

Comment: You are using a `form` but none of your form elements have `name`attributes. You need to use name attributes so that you can then use `serialize()` in jQuery.

Comment: okay so i can update all the fields using the id .. my problem is by the checkboxes only. When i check a checkbox and then update it update all checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

**Problems:**

1. you are creating your checkbox Ids as an array syntax `s[]`. I believe you are confusing it with the `name` attribute. Change this: `id='s[]'` to this: `name='s[]'`
2. `<font>` is no longer supported. Also, the opening and closing tags of that element is not correct.
3. where is your `ajax`? where's your `form`? where's your submit button? Without this info, you leave us to assume this is a form, and that your jquery function gets triggered when the form is submitted. If thats the case, then you need your `action`attribute with the URL that AJAX will use to send the request.

**Summary:**

Please be more descriptive, show your HTML, your PHP, jQuery properly so that we can best help you. In order to solve your problem you need to send an AJAX request. Find out how to do that, implement that in your code, and then we can continue from there.

Comment: i use bootstrap modal 
<button type="button"  onclick="updatedata('<?php echo $row['t_id'] ?>')" data-dismiss="modal"  class="btn btn-primary">Update</button> the button and ajax
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "updatedata.php?t_id="+t_id,
    data: datas,
    cache: false
 }).done(function( data ) {
   $('#info').html(data);
  viewdata();
 });

Comment: at this point what you need to do, and what would help us understand, is if you post all your PHP, HTML, and jQuery code. Without this im lost. update your original question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need help urgently with this. The main problem I see is that you are missing the `name` attribute in your `form` elements. You need to use `name` attributes so that when you gather the data in jQuery you can use the `.serialize()` function. I will sort of redo your code in a way that I think you have it working. I will delete all that bootstrap stuff and the non-related code so that you can see what I am doing:

I am assuming your data is coming from your database. I will use an array called `$data` to mimic that result set:

```
//your database data
$data = array(
    array(
        "t_id" => 1,
        "username" => "john",
        "Astatus" => "Wollte k T,Kunde Ni err.,N.Zuhaus"
    )
);

//your comparison data
$arrAstatus = array("Wollte k T", "Kunde Ni err.", "St .Gef", "N.Zuhaus", "Offen", "Negativ", "MJV", "Behan.", "Abgesagt", "Positiv");
```

Next, I assume you iterate through each result as `$row` and create your `forms`. I removed your classes/ids because we do not need them for this purpose. Instead, I placed the needed `name` attributes in your inputs:

```
<?php foreach ($data as $row) { ?>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>" class="form-control">
            <input type="text" name="t_id" value="<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>" class="form-control">

            <?php

            $iAstatus = explode(",", $row['Astatus']);
            foreach ($arrAstatus as $aAstatus) {
                if (in_array($aAstatus, $iAstatus))
                    echo "<label><input type='checkbox' name='s[]' value='$aAstatus'  checked>$aAstatus</label><br>";
                else
                    echo "<label><input type='checkbox' name='s[]' value='$aAstatus'>$aAstatus</label><br>";
            }
            ?>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
<?php } ?>
```

Lastly, your jQuery should be triggered when the form is submitted using the `.submit()` function. Once submitted, use `.serialize()` to obtain all inputs with the `name` attributes and send it through AJAX:

```
$('form').submit(function () {

    var datas = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submit.php",
        data: datas,
        cache: false
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Hope this helps.